# Laravel eloquent get index once

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have table contain user posts and each post has an image :-

table(posts): (id,title,image)

I am trying to build an image gallery where user can select from previously uploaded photos, this is query i use to get user previous used images:-

```
        $images = Auth::user()->posts()
        ->where('image','!=','NULL')
        ->select('image')
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->paginate(6);
        
        return response()->json($images);
```

The problem with above query is when the same image eg.(imageE.jpg) is used in many posts, the image get repeated in user gallery.

What should i add to the query above to retrieve only unique values

Comment: you have to generate a `unique` name for every file while saving it in the database

Comment: @Basharmal I am generating a unique name for a file, but i am not saving that file in separate table like (uploads) then referring it as FK in posts. Instead i am directly saving the file to posts table, so when user later want to create a new post i will show him option to select from previous uploaded photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
$images = Auth::user()->posts()
        ->where('image','!=','NULL')
        ->select('image')
        ->distinct()
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->paginate(6);
        
        return response()->json($images);
```

Adding the `distinct` function will change the query to not show multiples. More details can be found on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements